# Tfs Extension for a specific project

Tags: tfs

Im pretty new in TFS and need to create a hub extension. 
The thing is I can't find a way to specify a collection project for the extension so it will exist only when this project is selected on the TFS and not for all projects.
Maybe there is a way to specify this in the extension-manifest.json file?

Answer (score 0):

No, extensions are installed into the collection level https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions
Data storage is also either at the collection level or user level.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not support** for now. When you install a extension, you need to specify a collection, **the extension will be installed for all team projects under this collection.**

There has been a related uservoice, you could vote up it, TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion:

> Limit the custom extensions to specific projects only
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16469686-limit-the-custom-extensions-to-specific-projects-o